# SharePoint 2013 calendar in IOS renders differently

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

Most of the time Sharepoint Calendar in IOS renders differently as shown in the below screenshot which causes a problem in changing views between month/week/day view programmatically and also manually.  But its working fine in android.

**For example:**

```
 _MoveToDate(null,"week")
```

In rare cases, the Calendar webpart renders correctly as it would in safari browser. But am not sure what the causes the problem.

Have anyone faced similar issue, It seems like sharepoint Known Bugs?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

[image]

Comment: Which version of SharePoint?

Comment: @TrevorSeward Sharepoint Server 2013

Comment: Sharepoint 2013

Comment: Are you using any custom master page? If yes, can you apply seattle master page at https://site_url_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: @Ahmad Zia Yes, am using custom masterpage. And I think master page has no effect in it because, recently I found that when I click REQUEST DESKTOP SITE from chrome browsers(ios) option menu, everything works well and good.

Comment: It means both IE and chrome renders it correctly. I asked to apply seattle master as it is tested on almost all major web browsers and OS. Seattle should work on safari without any issues. This helps in isolating the issue if it is with the custom master page or not.

Comment: @AhmadZia Apologize for late reply.  Yes I tried using the seatle masterpage. Still the same issue.

Comment: So master page is not the issue, can you open the calendar page in chrome on mac/ios machine/os and inspect it to see any javascript or network errors in the console?

Comment: @AhmadZia Yeah Sure. I will let you know after trying.

Comment: @AhmadZia We debugged in ios and  figured out one post request is missing while switching to week view. In resource tab we found SP.UI.Applicationpages.calendar.debug.js is missing. We are not sure whether this the root cause. we  tried loaded that js manually by in master page. But still no luck